# how to convert weekly rows into daily

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data table, dt, that looks like

```
          date         value
 1: 2016-06-06             0
 2: 2016-06-13             0
 3: 2016-06-20             0
 4: 2016-06-27             0
 5: 2016-07-04             0
 6: 2016-07-11        213257
 7: 2016-07-18        513123
 8: 2016-07-25        162171
 9: 2016-08-01        162171
10: 2016-08-08        462171
11: 2016-08-15             0
12: 2016-08-22             0
13: 2016-08-29             0
14: 2016-09-05             0
15: 2016-09-12             0
16: 2016-09-19             0
17: 2016-09-26             0
```

As we can see the values are daily. I would like to convert these values to daily and at the date column to have the "daily date". So for instance, row 6 of dt, should be replaced by 7 rows, where in the `date` column should be the dates 
`2016-07-11` until `2016-07-17` , and in the value column, for each of these rows, it should have 213257 divided by 7

Comment: All the rows with `value` as 0 should be ignored and not expanded?

Comment: no, they should not be ignored

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    dt <- dt[,.(date=ymd(seq.Date(from = as.Date(date),to = as.Date(date)+6,
by= "day" )), value=value/7),by="date"]
```

This also works, but i end up with 2 columns named `date`, so i guess before doing this i should rename the `date` column to `date_temp` or something.

Answer (score 1):

This works as well:

```
dt[rep(1:nrow(dt),each=7)][,`:=`(date=date+seq_len(.N)-1,value=value/7),by=date]
```